# Can import Python module to Vyper smart contract?

Tags: python, vyper

I don't know my question is right or not. There is a Python module that we should rewrite its source code on a smart contract. Other hand, Vyper is a pythonic language for developing Ethereum smart contract. Is there any way to import that module to the Vyper smart contract instead rewriting its source code?

Answer (score 3):

Vyper runs on Ethereum Virtual Machine, not on a CPU. Because EVM is deterministic, it misses operations that are available on a normal CPU/machine, thus making all Python modules incompatible. You need to rewrite your code.